# Highcharts - Column Chart - Y Axis DateTime

Tags: highcharts

I hava a line chart on HighCharts that displays dateTimeLabels correctly. But if change it to type:column the labels are replaced by numbers and all columns have the same height.

http://highcharts.com/jsbin/ihorog/edit#javascript,live
(To check the error just uncomment type:column on jsbin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because a column is drawn as being from zero to the value and since your values are created by Date.UTC(), zero is Jan 1, 1970. Since the labels span such a large time span it is doing something weird. Specify a min for your yAxis and it will start from there.

http://highcharts.com/jsbin/uvuvoh/edit#javascript,live

```
yAxis: {
    min : Date.UTC(2013,0,1),
    ...
},
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked out great !! Since there was no min date labels the dateTimeLabelFormats property was using the year format since it was a large time span. Using min fixed my problem.